# Starting native app development in C++ for wearable device in Tizen IDE

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

How to download basic native C++ sample project for Tizen wearables in Tizen IDE.Currently I’m able to download sample project of C language only.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Currently C is the native language of Tizen  because most of the  API are written as C function. There is a C++ library called DALi. You will find several 
sample app in Tizen Studio under Mobile UI segment.

But if you want, you can still use C++ in your code. For that, you have to change some settings in  Tizen studio as follows

Step-1: You have to create cpp extension file to use cpp code by right clicking on src folder of your project. Go to

src --> New --> File--> file name must have .cpp extension

After that you have to change compiler settings for C++

Step-2: Right click on your project then go to

Properties --> C/C++ Build --> Settings --> Tool Settings --> C++ Compiler --> Dialect

Now select C++11 from "Language Standard" menu. After that Click OK to save it.

Step-3: Again Right click on project then go to

Properties --> C/C++ Build --> Tizen Settings --> Platform

Then goto "Toolchain Information" section and select any one from GCC-4.9 (default) or LLVM GCC-4.9 (default) from "Name" menu.
Finally click OK to save it.

Answer (score 2):

There's a nice guide how to use C++ in Tizen at http://Tizen.jdm.host 
Author is using some utility classes that make everything much easier. You should check it out.