# What is Tizen's native language?

Tags: c++, c, tizen, tizen-native-app

What is Tizen's native language ?
All samples are in C, but if I select from the *Project* menu into Tizen Studio's menu with

> New -> Class

I can only to create a C++ class file. Why is that so?
What language do you use to create your Tizen applications?
Or is there a Tizen website for developers in addition to Samsung's Tizen website?

Comment: c does not have classes

Comment: https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/c-tizen-native-application?langredirect=1

Answer (score 4):

C and C++, both are used for Tizen Native application development. However, Most of the given sample applications are written in C and the default IDE settings can’t recognize C++ code. So, a beginner in Tizen development may face hard time to write code in C++ as he/she can’t use many magical features of C++. This article demonstrates how to make Tizen studio C++11 compatible so that developers can use C++ for Tizen native application development.

See these tutorials:

1. https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/c-tizen-native-application
2. https://developer.tizen.org/development/training/native-application/getting-started/creating-your-first-tizen-mobile-native-application

Also see this discussion thread: "Starting native app development in C++ for wearable device in Tizen IDE".
[Starting native app development in C++ for wearable device in Tizen IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40734830/starting-native-app-development-in-c-for-wearable-device-in-tizen-ide)

Tizen Native API is carefully selected and tightly managed APIs from the Tizen native subsystems. The Tizen Native API Specification available in the Tizen SDK shows full list of the selected native subsystem APIs.
Check below link for The Basics of Tizen Native API Reference:
https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application

A Tizen Web application is basically a Web site stored on a wearable device. You can create it using Web-native languages, such as HTML5, CSS, and JavaScript.
See this tutorial: https://developer.tizen.org/development/training/web-application/getting-started/creating-your-first-tizen-wearable-web-application

The Tizen Web Device API, based on JavaScript, provides you advanced access to the device's platform capabilities. For Tizen Mobile Web Device API Reference see this link: https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/web-application

The Tizen .NET framework allows you to easily and efficiently create applications for Tizen. 
See this tutorial: https://developer.tizen.org/development/training/.net-application/creating-your-first-tizen-.net-application

Tizen .NET provides a rich set of interfaces allowing you to build compelling TV, mobile, and wearable(preview) applications which achieve native performance.
See this link for Tizen .NET API Guides: https://developer.tizen.org/development/guides/.net-application

Different technical projects are also available with project-code. 
Follow this link: https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech

Comment: Can you write a web application with some native bits in it? Like in a Cordova app you can have a native plugin with which you can exchange data.